# Вызвать API по расписанию из MySQL

Tags: mysql, api

Подскажите как реализовать следующую штуку:
Есть API, который возвращает список событий на день. Есть БД, я использую MySQL.
Мне необходимо по расписанию запускать вызов этого API и результаты класть в БД. Причём после каждого вызова API затирать данные и записывать новые

Comment: Из самого mysql никакой api вызвать нельзя. Вам надо написать скрипт на любом удобном языке программирования и поставить его запуск в cron

Comment: @Mike спасибо. А есть какая нибудь инструкция или обучалка как это сделать?